# setup UWSGI debug in VS code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, uwsgi, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to debug a local uwsgi with VS code. Unfortunately I can't attach the python interpreter to my Visual Code debug:

VSCode launch.json configuration:

```
{
        "type": "python",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "Launch uWSGI",
        "port": 9090,
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "pathMappings": [
            {
                "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",  // You may also manually specify the directory containing your source code.
                "remoteRoot": "${workspaceFolder}" // Linux example; adjust as necessary for your OS and situation.
            }
        ]
    }
```

And uwsgi config:

```
[development]
virtualenv = %(chdir)/../env/env1/
http = 127.0.0.1:9090
```

Then I run uwsgi in my local enabled venv:

```
uwsgi --ini conf.d/uwsgi/dev.ini
```

With the following output:

```
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uWSGI http bound on 0.0.0.0:3001 fd 4
uWSGI http bound on 127.0.0.1:9090 fd 5
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:42183 (port auto-assigned) fd 3
Python version: 3.7.2 (default, Jan 11 2019, 21:31:15)  [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
```

Comment: Were you able to do it?